# Set a variable through the URL in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

Hey i am wondering if the following is possible:

There is a single page website for example index.html
and a varibale for example 
    MyVariable = 123; 
within the js script of this index.html.
The URL example.com will show the index.html

Now is it possible to share a link that looks like example.com/1234 or something similar which then shows the normal index.html file but it changed the variable MyVariable to "1234" inside the js script?

Thank you! :)

Comment: The only possible way that this could work is if the variable `myVariable` was not assigned as a local variable to it's function, then you could modify it after page load, but not before, because you would have to modify the file contents.

Comment: That is fine. And how would i realize this? Can you provide a code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you'll need to redirect server-side any URL of the form `example.com/*` to your `index.html` file. How to do this depends on the server you are using.

For Apache, you'll want to edit your `.htaccess` file or configuration to add a rewriting rule:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

Source: http://www.josscrowcroft.com/2012/code/htaccess-for-html5-history-pushstate-url-routing/

Then, in you JavaScript code, you can access the current location (URL) via the `window.location` object.
You'll be interested in the `pathname` property, that will contain in your example: `/1234`.

To extract the value you'll have to do something like this:

```
var MyVariable = window.location.pathname.substring(1);
```

Comment: Actually, you would want to omit the `var `declaration.

Comment: That sounds really reasonable. Can you give me further information how i could redirect the urls?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I think one can understand whether to put `var` or not. For the sake of the example, not putting `var` would be a very bad practice.

Comment: @MarcSter Which server are you using?

Comment: Do you mean it is only possible without the var declaration, but it is unsafe to run a website like that? I am using an Apache

Comment: No this code is perfectly reasonable. The only reason to not use `var` here is if you want to declare `MyVariable` somewhere else and only modify its value here. For the Apache redirect, I'll update the post :)

Comment: Thank you for providing the .htacces code. I have a further question, though. My .htacces file is in my example.com directory. But i want to use this for the directory /VariableChanger on my webserver, which is set for (just an example) Variablechanger.com.

Comment: @MarcSter Unfortunately, I don't use Apache anymore, so I'm a little rusty but I guess you'll be interested in virtual hosts for this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html.

Answer (score 1):

i would recommend using php get , if you are using apache , where you can transfer your variable through a link

call you page like index.php?myvariable=1234

```
<html>
<body>

your variable is <?php echo $_GET["myvariable"]; ?>


</body>
</html>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: Sounds good, how would i get the value of that PHP variable into my js variable?

Comment: simply using var my_updated_variable = "<?php echo $_GET["myvariable"];?>";

Comment: Thank you very much! The best solution for my purpose! But i will accept the answer of ngrymen because the question was about doing it with javascript.. but thank you anyway!